# Check that a given date does lie between two existing dates inside a datatable

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one table which can store employee leave start date and end date 
like so:

```
EmployeeID   ManagerId   leaveStartDate   leaveEndDate       isApproved

1           14           10/02/2014         15/02/2014       approved
4           17           10/02/2014         12/02/2014       rejected
```

I need check when manager login is its any employee is on leave? if yes then manager can assign that employees work to other employee.For that I have to check wheather current system time is lies between leaveStartDate and leaveEndDate.How can I do that ?

Comment: select * from table where getdate() between startdate and enddate and isapproved='approved' and managerid=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna filter with IsApprved as well try this.

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployeeLeaves WHERE Date(Getdate()) between leaveStartDate and leaveEndDate AND  isApproved='approved'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

this can solve this:

*abc is your table name

```
select * from abc where isApproved="approved" and Date(Getdate()) between leaveStartDate and leaveEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine thanks

```
 select EmployeeId from tblName where Getdate() between leaveStartDate and leaveEndDate and isApproved='Approve' and ManagerId=@mgrId
```